# Is using admin database in MongoDB a bad practice if I use only one database inside and one user in general?

Tags: mongodb

Just as in the title.
Is there any point of caring about what database I put my data to if I don't plan anywhere in the future to use more than one user and more than one database?

Will it be a problem if I put my application data into `admin` db in the future? I can restore my backups and they work.

Comment: Best to look at some of the content in [dba.se] - this is off-topic here. But in general, this falls under the category of 'antipattern' - especially around security and data access.

Comment: Alright, i'm gonna move on there with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases `admin`, `local` and `config` are MongoDB internal databases, you should not use them for any application data. This rule applies for any database. You may get trouble with permissions or naming conflicts.